# Keep Mac from locking after sleep

Tags: sleep-wake, screensaver, screen-lock

A brand new Mac locks after it goes to sleep, or when the screensaver happens.

How can I keep the Mac from locking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to System Preferences > Security & Privacy and disable the "Require password x seconds after sleep..." by unticking the checkbox:

[image]